# Is there a way to exclude datasets in CKAN plugin ckanext-datajson output?

Tags: json, plugins, ckan

We have installed ckanext-datajson to export our datasets into U.S. Project Open Data metadata specification v.1.1 compatible format. However, there are data we do not want to appear in the output because the datasets are confidential. We thought about making the datasets private which does exclude them, but it also prevents anyone who is not in the organization from seeing the dataset, which we don't want.

Does anyone know a way to prevent datasets from outputting to JSON that doesn't involve making them private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer requires coding, so if this is an option for you, you might find it helpful.

I don't know specifically about the datajson extension, but we had a similar use case for the dcat extension. [ckanext-dcat](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-dcat) provides metadata about all datasets as RDF through an endpoint (`/catalog.xml`). We have one user who wanted to exclude specific datasets, so we implemented a [custom extension](https://github.com/berlinonline/ckanext-dcatde_berlin) with a modified version of this endpoint that filters out certain datasets. Specifically, we filter out all datasets that have the value `harvest-fisbroker` for the (custom) attribute `berlin_source`.

Down the line, the DCAT catalog endpoint works by calling [package_search](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search). `package_search` provides an `fq`-parameter (filter query), which can be used to filter the result by any attribute. We set this parameter in our extension as part of a `data_dict`, which then gets passed to the `dcat_catalog_show` action, which in turn calls `package_search` to generate its response.

```py
from flask import Blueprint, make_response
from ckan.plugins import toolkit
from ckanext.dcat.utils import CONTENT_TYPES

def read_catalog(format):

    data_dict = {
        'page': toolkit.request.params.get('page'),
        'modified_since': toolkit.request.params.get('modified_since'),
        'format': format,
        'fq': '-berlin_source:harvest-fisbroker',
    }

    response = toolkit.get_action('dcat_catalog_show')({}, data_dict)

    response = make_response(response)
    response.headers['Content-type'] = CONTENT_TYPES[format]

    return response


no_fisbroker_api = Blueprint('no_fisbroker_api', __name__)
no_fisbroker_api.add_url_rule(u'/catalog_no_fb.<format>',
                        methods=[u'GET'], view_func=read_catalog)
```

The code above is stripped down to the bare minimum the illustrate the idea. The complete code for our custom endpoint (it's implemented as a Flask Blueprint) is a little too much to show here, but you can find it in the repository for our extension: [no_fisbroker_blueprint.py](https://github.com/berlinonline/ckanext-dcatde_berlin/blob/master/ckanext/dcatde_berlin/no_fisbroker_blueprint.py)

Comment: Thank you. This will work for us. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like the extensions allows any kind of [custom filtering](https://github.com/GSA/ckanext-datajson/blob/124d5b0d4a53b532a23651a4c7a336b4cbe6a15b/ckanext/datajson/blueprint.py#L390). You can ask the maintainers directly about potential alternatives in the [extension repo](https://github.com/GSA/ckanext-datajson/issues).